# Scrolling UL of page height with header with variable width

Tags: css

I have a `ul` that's the height of the page. I'd like it to be able to scroll inside of that ul. That can be seen here: http://d.saew.it/pRyz

As you can see, it can scroll as the height of the page. Now, I also want it to have a header, as you can see there. It should be "fixed" on the top, but the width of the `ul` list is variable, therefore I can not set it to fixed as it can't be centered in a parent of variable width.

Now, what I have works almost perfectly, except for the fact that the `height: 100%` of the `ul` to be the height of the parent (same as the window), while the `div` header still takes up space above it. Therefore, this throws the `ul` a few pixels off the end of the parent element. Check it out: http://d.saew.it/NXL1

Is there any way of accomplishing what I'm trying in pure CSS?

Edit:

The code is in stylus, but anyone should still be able to read it:

```
div.ul-header
    background-color #E6E6E6
    text-align center
    margin 0
ul
    background-color #E6E6E6
    height 100%
    margin 0
    overflow-x hidden
```

All parents of these elements have `height: 100%;` on them to allow for it to reach the window's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear what you want, but [this](http://jsbin.com/ukumix/1/edit) is my best guess.

Basically what you're doing is using absolute positioning and overflow rules to control what scrolls, and where it appears.

The container holds both the header and the scrollable list, and has `height: 100%` within the page body.  It also has `position: relative` so that its child elements can be positioned absolutely.

The child elements - the header and the list - both have `position: absolute`. This is so that you can force the list to have a height that's both restricted (so its content overflows) and variable (according to the height of its parent), i.e. it should always be exactly the height of its parent, minus the height of the header.  Note that the value of its `top` property needs to correspond to the *total* height of the header - including padding and border.

Then to get your scrolling list, you can just use `overflow: auto` on the list.

To get your centered text in the header is as simple as `text-align: center`, which will work no matter the width of the container.